# How to use dynamic substitute text when text starts to overflow?

Tags: css, html

If I have three text strings known at page load time (but not at design time), such as:

1. The full text could be somewhat long.
2. Partial text is shorter.
3. Tiny text.

How do I place the text in some HTML element (div or span is fine) with no wrapping such when the user does some action which resized the HTML element, that the longest text is preferred, but if the text will overflow, switch to the next shortest text which does not overflow?  Resizing smaller than the smallest text will hide any overflow (i.e. the HTML element will have overflow: hidden).

Comment: Is using jQuery/JavaScript allowed?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript (or jQuery or even AngularJS) is allowed, though I'd much prefer solutions that can be achieved with just CSS, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with CSS as long as you're willing to constrain the height. Since you wanted only 1 line of text, constraining the height to, for example, `1em` doesn't seem like an unreasonable restriction.

When you float an element, it will flow to the next line when there is not enough space on the first line. Each line in this solution has two items on it:

1. A breaker element with a width of `1px`. Unfortunately this element must have some width in order to participate in the flow according to my testing.
2. The text to display.

The text must be arranged shortest-to-longest and must not have a transparent background. Using a transparent background would allow the shorter text to show through.

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 1em; /* Must be fixed height */
  width: 100%; /* Or any width you want */
  overflow: hidden; /* Make sure that the elements that are bumped down don't show */
  border: 1px solid red; /* For example only */
}

.container p {
  position: relative; /* Relative to allow shifting elements up */
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1em; /* Text block must be fixed height */
  background-color: white; /* Text block must be opaque */
}

.container .break {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1em; /* Must be the same height as a text block */
}

/* Shift each longer text block up to sit atop the first one */
.container p:nth-child(4) {
  top: -1em;
}
.container p:nth-child(6) {
  top: -2em;
}


/* Code below is just to animate the width for the sake of this example, and is not part of the solution */
@keyframes changewidth {
  from { width: 100%; }
  to { width: 1%; }
}

.container {
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: changewidth;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="break"></div>
  <p>Short summary</p>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <p>This is a shorter version of the summary text.</p>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <p>This is a really long version of the summary text. I could go on forever. Isn't this great?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with CSS. Use JavaScript and loop through all of the versions. Leave the one that fits. You can measure div height to determine if text fits.

**EDIT (added example):**

HTML

```
<div class="ft" data-sh="{{ short-text }} data-tn=" {{ tiny-text }}">{{ long-text }}</div>
```

jQuery

```
function fits(ele) {
   var cur_height = ele.height();
   ele.css('white-space', 'nowrap');
   var obl_height = ele.height();
   return cur_height == obl_height;
}

$(function(){

   $('.ft').each(function() {

       if( ! fits($(this)) {

         $(this).html($(this).data('sh');

         if( ! fits($(this)) {

             $(this).html($(this).data('tn');
         }
       }
   })
});
```

This could be written better, but I hope this will give you an idea. Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any HTML code but here is a working version with jQuery for this kind of HTML structure.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hfcrkv3/)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <p class="large">I am a paragraph</p>

    <p class="med">I am a paragraph</p>

    <p class="small">I am a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.mydiv {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.med {
    font-size: .8em;
}

.small {
    font-size: .2em;
}

.mydiv p {
    display: none;
}

p.large {
    display: block;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('.mydiv').children('p').each(function(i, el) {
    if (this.scrollWidth >  $(el).innerWidth()) {
        $(el).css('display', 'none');
        $(el).next('p').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my question may not have been clear - I will edit.  The container may be resized by the user, and if it is resized, then change text.  Also, the container element (in your case, .mydiv) will have overflow hidden.